# How to create multiple instance of Windows Service?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I want to run multiple instances of a Windows Service installed on a server  without installing it again.

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: It's not possible. You could create differently named services (perhaps with different command line parameters), or have a single windows service that spawns other processes, but you can't do what you've described in your question - it just doesn't make sense. Please can you **edit your question** to describe the background to your problem, and exactly what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: You might want to rethink this and have one windows service that has multiple threads running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A service "installation" is really just adding a mapping between a name, an executable, and a few other bits of metadata. A service, once installed, is either running (once), or it isn't. To have multiple instances running *as services*, they would have to be registered with different names, which basically means installing it multiple times. That does *not*, however, mean that you need multiple different copies of the executable.

The way I do it is to subclass `Installer` such that it creates a `ServiceInstaller` and `ServiceProcessInstaller`, and gives a `ServiceName` (at runtime, via the custom installer) to the `ServiceInstaller` instance, then use `ManagedInstallerClass` at runtime - basically making a standalone exe capable of installing and uninstalling itself as a service (as many times as you like), using command-line parameters to specify the name.

Comment: I still wonder why TS wants to do this and whether it's the best idea.

Comment: Here's more details. Usefull stuff. http://journalofasoftwaredev.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/multiple-instances-of-same-windows-service/

Comment: Can you post the Installer Subclass please?