# Run service instance 1 of n

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, multiprocessing

I need to create windows service that can run in multiple instances. I need to be able to pass parameters in which specify the details. For example,

something like

```
\Services\emailengine.exe 1 3
\Services\emailengine.exe 2 3
\Services\emailengine.exe 3 3
```

So, the first parameter is the instance and the second param is the total number of instances. So, the above are saying

```
Run instance 1 of 3
Run instance 2 of 3
Run instance 3 of 3
```

if I do something like this

```
\Services\emailengine.exe 4 3
```

It should throw an exception, as current instance can't be greater than total number of allowed instances. And if again I start/install something like this

```
\Services\emailengine.exe 2 3
```

it should still throw an exception as the second instance is already running.

I could provide some code, but I have no idea where to start in the first place. The service is all build, up and running. But it is just a normal windows service that you install and are good to go. Now I need to make it like what I described, and like I said I have no idea how to approach this.

Can anyone please suggest what approach should I take? I Googled but didn't find anything much relevant.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: You CAN'T have multiple instances of a service running under the same name. [Take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15785420/1082327). Not really sure what your requirements are or why you would want different instances of the same service, but one thing you can do is create a parent service, supply arguments to that service and have it **install** different instances of `emailengine` under different names. For example, `\Services\Parent.exe 2 3` would install two services: `emailengine1.exe` and `emailengine2.exe`.

Comment: What business problem do you want to solve with this application?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov
Is is going to process emails in my application queue and send them.

Comment: What is your application? Where does it take emails and where does it send them?