# C# Error : Service cannot be started. An instance of the service is already running

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

Was wondering if anyone could help me out with this, im new to working with services so some help would be very much appreciated.
Bascailly what I want to do is run multiple instances of a service by creating numeorus different threads and calling a ThreadHandler method which creates the service.

"Service cannot be started. An instance of the service is already running"

What is currently happening though is that when I start the service the first instance works fine but checking the event logs i see this error regarding the second instance

```
//Creates multiple thread instances
foreach (ThreadManagerPoco threadManager in ThreadManagers)
{
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadHandler));
thread.Name = threadManager.Name;
thread.Start();
}
//Called from program > Main() with thread info     
public static void ThreadHandler()
{
Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
new MyService(thread.Name),
};
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785341/how-to-create-multiple-instance-of-window-service

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve].